# Windows 2008 file share permissions

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, permissions, share

How can you stop users from moving folders and files in a Windows 2008 share, but still allow them to create new folders, rename folders, open files and save files?

Answer (score 2):

You can't without breaking permission inheritance on the folders that you don't want moved. These are the relevant permissions:

```
List Folders / Read Data  
Traverse Folder / Execute File
Create Files / Write Data  
Create Folders / Append Data
```

The problem is that `Create Folders / Append Data` and `Create Files / Write Data` is what lets you move a folder, but it's also essential to let them make new folders and data.

Depending on your directory structure, you could give only `Traverse Folder / Execute File` and `List Folders / Read Data` on the folders that you don't want moved and them give Modify (or whatever) on the children of that folder.

Example:

Assume a directory structure like this:

-top_folder
--subfolder1
--subfolder2

If you set top_folder to: No inheritance, `Traverse / List for This Folder Only`, `Modify for All Subfolders and Files`

Then they wouldn't be able to change top_folder in any way, but they could modify anything under it.